# How to use Bootstrap 4 & Sass on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: css, sass, minify, visual-studio-2019, autoprefixer

I've just upgraded to VS2019 and found it doesn't come with much out of the box in terms of modern web development.

I'm looking to compile Boostrap with some variable changes & run the results through autoprefixer and then minify. I'm not yet ready to move to core so the project is in .net 4.7.

I've found Web Compiler, which will compile & minify the Sass but this is very dangerous to rely on because it doesn't autoprefix bootstrap. Using the default distribution of Bootstrap you get autoprefixing so it will work on older browsers as well. Just using web compiler you will get a nice, tight minified file customized to your liking that will look great on your dev machine and then fail in an untraceable way on deployment for users with older browsers.

I've also found the Autoprefixer extension, which doesn't seem to work at all. There is an autoprefixer menu in the context menu but it is greyed out. There seems to be no way to configure tasks as far as I can tell so even if it did work you have to right click on stuff each time.

So I'm wondering why I spent over $1000 to upgrade to VS2019 when it just doesn't do the basics of modern web development. Would it have been better just to use free tools? Or is there some way to get it to work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if I understand you right, but you could use a gulpfile.js to compile SASS Files. Worked pretty well in my .net 4.7 project.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into Gulp.

Comment: did you get it to work with Gulp? Web Compiler is not working properly with Boostrap it seems.